# "Pattern matching" of algebraic type data constructors

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

Let's consider a data type with many constructors:

```
data T = Alpha Int | Beta Int | Gamma Int Int | Delta Int
```

I want to write a function to check if two values are produced with the same constructor:

```
sameK (Alpha _) (Alpha _) = True
sameK (Beta _) (Beta _) = True
sameK (Gamma _ _) (Gamma _ _) = True
sameK _ _ = False
```

Maintaining `sameK` is not much fun, it cannot be checked for correctness easily. For example, when new constructors are added to `T`, it's easy to forget to update `sameK`. I omitted one line to give an example:

```
-- it’s easy to forget:
-- sameK (Delta _) (Delta _) = True
```

The question is how to avoid boilerplate in `sameK`? Or how to make sure it checks for all `T` constructors?

---

*The workaround I found is to use separate data types for each of the constructors, deriving `Data.Typeable`, and declaring a common type class, but I don't like this solution, because it is much less readable and otherwise just a simple algebraic type works for me:*

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Typeable

class Tlike t where
  value :: t -> t
  value = id

data Alpha = Alpha Int deriving Typeable
data Beta = Beta Int deriving Typeable
data Gamma = Gamma Int Int deriving Typeable
data Delta = Delta Int deriving Typeable

instance Tlike Alpha
instance Tlike Beta
instance Tlike Gamma
instance Tlike Delta

sameK :: (Tlike t, Typeable t, Tlike t', Typeable t') => t -> t' -> Bool
sameK a b = typeOf a == typeOf b
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering. All of your answers were useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the Data.Data module, the `toConstr` function in particular. Along with `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}` that will get you a 1-line solution which works for any type which is an instance of `Data.Data`. You don't need to figure out all of SYB!

If, for some reason (stuck with Hugs?), that is not an option, then here is a very ugly and very slow hack. It works only if your datatype is `Show`able (e.g. by using `deriving (Show)` - which means no function types inside, for example).

```
constrT :: T -> String
constrT = head . words . show
sameK x y = constrT x == constrT y
```

`constrT` gets the string representation of the outermost constructor of a `T` value by showing it, chopping it up into words and then getting the first. I give an explicit type signature so you're not tempted to use it on other types (and to evade the monomorphism restriction).

**Some notable disadvantages:**

- This breaks horribly when your type has infix constructors (such as `data T2 = Eta Int | T2 :^: T2`)
- If some of your constructors have a shared prefix, this is going to get slower, as a larger part of the strings has to be compared.
- Doesn't work on types with a custom `show`, such as many library types.

That said, it *is* Haskell 98... but that's about the only nice thing I can say about it!

Answer (score 15):

Another possible way:

```
sameK x y = f x == f y
  where f (Alpha _)   = 0
        f (Beta _)    = 1
        f (Gamma _ _) = 2
        -- runtime error when Delta value encountered
```

A runtime error is not ideal, but better than silently giving the wrong answer.

Comment: I like it. GHC with `-Wall` kindly reports non-exaustive pattern matches in the definition  of `f', so runtime error may be prevented. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to use a generics library like Scrap Your Boilerplate or uniplate to do this in general.

If you don't want to be so heavy-handed, you can use Dave Hinton's solution, together with the empty record shortcut:

```
...
where f (Alpha {}) = 0
      f (Beta {}) = 1
      f (Gamma {}) = 2
```

So you don't have to know how many args each constructor has.  But it obviously still leaves something to be desired.

Comment: Record braces bind stronger than anything else, so technically you don't need the parentheses. `f Alpha {} = 0` will work fine, although I'm not sure how readable that is, it sort of looks like `f` takes two arguments. I sometimes dabble with `f Alpha{} = 0`...

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, "Scrap Your Boilerplate" library will help.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate

Comment: I assume I can start with these papers: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the generics to eliminate the boilerplate.  Your code is a textbook example why I (and many others *never* use the `_` wildcard at top level).  While it is tedious to write out all the cases, it is less tedious than dealing with the bugs.

In this happy example I would not only use Dave Hinton's solution but would slap an INLINE pragma on the auxiliary function `f`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking. Thank you for advice.