# Force GHC to ignore missing type constraint

Tags: haskell, constraints, ghc

I built a type `Sup` that embeds a value of another type `t` using constructor subtyping.

```
data Sup t = ...
           | Sub t 
           deriving Eq
```

Because the part omitted from `Sup` contains lots of constructors, none of which use `t`, I want to *derive* `Eq (Sup t)` rather than give a manual instance.

A type constraint `Eq t` is now in place on the instance of `(==)` for `Sup t`:

`(==) :: Eq t => Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool`

The predicate `isSub :: Sup t -> Bool` is defined as follows:

```
isSub :: Sup t -> Bool
isSub (Sub _) = True
isSub _       = False
```

With the help of this predicate I would like to define the following operator:

```
supEq :: Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool
supEq x y = not (isSub x) && not (isSub y) && x == y
```

The above definition is not accepted by GHC, as the type-constraint `Eq t` is missing. However, thanks to lazy evaluation, I know that equality between values of type `t` is never actually used.

Is there a way that I can force GHC to ignore the missing type-constraint?
Alternatively, is there a way I could have defined `Sup` or `supEq` to get the desired result: a definition of `supEq` without having to propagate a redundant type constraint wherever `supEq` is used and without having to give a manual instance for  `Eq (Sup t)`.

Comment: What use case do you have for this construct?

Comment: So you want `supEq` to judge two values of the form `Sup a` always as unequal, even `supEq (Sub 1) (Sub 1) ≡ False`? Might be helpful to clearly state this in the question.

Comment: I think you can use Data.Data.toConstr (see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html) to get at a representation of the constructor used and build from there. Also see [my previous answer to a similar-ish question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628104/pattern-matching-of-algebraic-type-data-constructors)/2630312#2630312

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest thing to do is define a custom `Eq (Sup t)` instance.

```
instance (Eq t) => Eq (Sup t) where
  (Sub a) == (Sub b) = a == b
  A == A = True
  ...
```

Alternatively, if you want `==` to behave like `supEq` (so you don't need `supEq` at all), you can write the instance without the constraint:

```
instance Eq (Sup t) where
  (Sub a) == (Sub b) = False
  A == A = True
  ...
```

Another approach is to split `Sup t` into two data types:

```
data Sup' = A | B | ... | Z deriving (Eq) -- nothing depends on `t`
data Sup t = Sub t | Sup'

supEq :: Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool
supEq (Sub _) _ = False
supEq _ (Sub _) = False
supEq a b = a == b
```

Of course yet a final option is to subvert the type system. This is almost certainly the wrong thing to do, but I'll leave that determination to you.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Constraint

supEq :: forall t . Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool
supEq x y = let Dict = unsafeCoerce (Dict :: Dict ()) :: Dict (Eq t)
            in not (isSub x) && not (isSub y) && x == y
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain the `Dict` business?

Comment: The constraint-less instance in the second example has a `(==)` that isn't reflexive, which makes it unadvisable.

Comment: In the last example, I create a `Dict (Eq t)` out of thin air using `unsafeCoerce`. By pattern matching on the result (`Dict`), I get a (completely bogus) constraint for `(Eq t)`, which is needed to call `==`. If everything works out like you hope, the bogus `Eq t` constraint is never accessed, so you can get away with that. It is extremely fragile, and again, not recommended.

Comment: Does the newish deferred type error machinery support this sort of thing safely? Sticking with your current approach, you could probably make things safer by constructing a type `newtype Bogus = Bogus Any` with `_ == _ = error ...` and coercing `Dict (Eq Bogus)`. Actually, you probably have another problem, with coherence, since you don't have a phantom like `reflection`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of getting rid of the `Eq` constraint if you use `(==)` while sticking with the unsurprising derived instance. Furthermore, as far as `supEq` is concerned your invariant is not being enforced (consider what would happen if you committed a mistake and swapped `True` and `False` in `isSub`). You are probably better off writing `supEq` in terms of `Sup` pattern matches alone:

```
data Sup t = Foo
           | Bar
           | Sub t 
           deriving Eq

supEq :: Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool
supEq (Sub _) _ = False
supEq _ (Sub _) = False
supEq Foo Foo = True
supEq Bar Bar = True
supEq _ _ = False
```

If there are enough cases that writing `supEq` in this way becomes annoying, you can split the non-`Sub` cases into a separate type, as in the next-to-last example in crockeea's answer, reproduced below for the sake of completeness:

```
data Sup' = Foo | Bar deriving (Eq)
data Sup t = Sub t | NotSub Sup' deriving (Eq)

supEq :: Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool
supEq (Sub _) _ = False
supEq _ (Sub _) = False
supEq (NotSub a) (NotSub b) = a == b
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course the simplest solution is to split your type into two types, as others have suggested. But this creates syntactic noise - an extra level of constructors. If you want the best of both you could use [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/Data-Reflection.html):

```
import Data.Reflection
import Data.Proxy 
import Data.Coerce 

data Sup t = Sub t | A | B | C | D | E -- .. etc
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

We will now use the generated `Eq` code for `Sup`, but substitute in a different function, not `(==)`, when comparing `Sub` with `Sub`.

First you need some setup (I think this should be in the `reflection` package itself - it has similair code for `Monoid` and `Applicative`):

```
newtype ReifiedEq a = ReifiedEq { eq :: a -> a -> Bool } 
newtype ReflectedEq s a = ReflectedEq a 

instance Reifies s (ReifiedEq a) => Eq (ReflectedEq s a) where 
  (==) = coerce (eq (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)))
```

This is the heart of the solution - a value of type `ReflectedEq s a` is just an `a`, but when compared for equality uses the equality function provided by `Reifies`, which you can specify at any time. Note that the `reflection` package uses type level machinery to prevent multiple `Eq` instances from being used in the same context.

Now you can write a function even more general than your desired one:

```
supEqWith :: (t -> t -> Bool) -> Sup t -> Sup t -> Bool 
supEqWith k x y = reify (ReifiedEq k) (\p -> h p x == h p y) where 
  h :: Proxy s -> Sup a -> Sup (ReflectedEq s a) 
  h _ = coerce
```

This function simply compares the `Sup` values for equality, using the specified function (`k`) to compare `t` values inside `Sub`. The `h` function is needed to specify the phantom type parameter (`s`) correctly, otherwise it is ambiguous.

Your desired function is simply:

```
supEq = supEqWith (\_ _ -> False)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `Sup` type can be a functor in `t` (`deriving Functor` would work on the example you've given), and you know that none of the other constructors use `t`, then you could `fmap (const ())` it.

Then you've got a guarantee that the `t` won't affect the equality check interestingly and don't need the original `t` to have `Eq`. You just need to guard the case when both inputs were some `Sub _` so that you return false instead of true.

```
subEq (Sub _) _ = False
subEq _ (Sub _) = False
subEq x y = fmap (const ()) x == fmap (const ()) y
```

Even if you don't want to make `Sup` a functor, you could still implement `submap :: (a -> b) ->Sup a -> Sup b` and use that.